# How do I find out my IP address on a unix-like box?

Tags: linux, unix, tcpip

How do I find out my IP address on a unix box?  I've tried

```
ifconfig
```

but it doesn't exist on the system.

Comment: Did you try as root? Also what OS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ifconfig is usually in /sbin. Depending on what system you're running this mightn't be on your path (in particular, RedHat systems don't include this on the default path)

Try:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig
```

If it works then that's the issue, and you should change your path via your .bashrc (or whatever shell you're using).

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

Comment: Some unix variants need the "`-a`" option passed to ifconfig to get informative output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the [`host`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_host.htm) command. Of course, you will have to specify the name of the machine that you are on.

Comment: This makes the assumption that the computer is on the internet, not behind NAT, has a working DNS server configured, and a hostname.

If you're on a TCP/IP network that isn't connected to the internet, then this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind some sort of NAT device, that device probably has an http interface that provides this information. First, find out its IP address either from the documentation or from the output of the route command. There should be a line that looks like this:

```
default         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ath0
```

Then connect to that IP address with your browser and see what you can find out. The rest depends on what kind of NAT device you're using.